# neo4j makeAugmentedSchema?

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I am building a database api with graphql and Neo4j. I am building out my schema using makeAugmentedSchema which comes from the package neo4j-graphql-js which generated mutations and querys for you based of of your schema. I am trying to add some custom resolves to help Authenticate users however I can figure out how to call the existing mutations created by makeAugmentedSchema or if that is even possible?

```
const schema = makeAugmentedSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  config: {
    auth: {
      isAuthenticated: true,
    }
  }
});
```

This is in my server file where I am creating this Augmented schema which creates mutations like create, update, and delete. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to handle auth so am attempting to create a custom resolver called registerUser that encrypts the password and then run the createUser mutation after but not sure how to bring in those existing mutations. Here is what it looks like now.

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { schema } from './graphql-schema';

export const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    registerUser: async (_, { email, password }) => {
      const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      console.log(schema, 'herrrr');

      await schema.User.create({
        email,
        password: hashPassword
      })
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

I am wanting to handle auth without using Auth0. Being new to neo4j and not really sure about the best approach any advise on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for thus also. Can't find any examples anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

So you are deconstructing the `args` param to get the password and hash it before creating the user. Instead of creating a new resolver to handle this hashing, you could just redefine the CreateUser resolver here and then pass the modified `args` to a `neo4jgraphql` call, like so:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { schema } from './graphql-schema';

export const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    CreateUser: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
      const password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      args = {
          ...args,
          password,
      }
      return neo4jgraphql(obj, args, context, info);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!